# xamarin.forms change images in high ratio

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

I want to create loader screen.

I have 100 png images for 0 - 100 precentage.

I create an image and replace the image.source every 100 mili.

The problem is that sometimes the prev image isn't loading before the current image's loading so the loader looks bad...

Is there a fast way to load / replace images ?

I tried FFimageLoading but the result in cachedImage there is even worse

Comment: Hi I'm one of the FFImageLoading author. What did you experience with the lib?

Comment: when working with cachedIMage FFImageLoading and loading lots of images at high rate (switching image every 100 mili), there wasn't smooth switching of images - it took the image longer time to load in comparisson to regular Image.

The image size was png of 60KB